# How to center text with letter-spacing?

Tags: html, css

I have a centered title with quite a bit of letter-spacing (90px) and the spacing applied to the last letter disturbs the symmetry of the text. How do I fix that?

Comment: A code sample would help us to understand what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `text-indent` to rectify this

```css
.box {
  letter-spacing: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(red 0 0) center/2px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">HELLO</div>
<div class="box" style="text-indent:60px;">HELLO</div>
```